# SSRS reports is showing as listed directory

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting

How can I get SSRS reports to show a web page view?

When I go to the SSRS reports page, it's not showing the web page view. It shows a list of data sources, data sets and report folders.

After going inside the reports folder, I can invoke the report by clicking on them without any issues.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B55EKwlB3BuINk1GeU9WRUoxM1E/edit?usp=sharing

Please look at the image above.

Comment: Can you please update the link in the question? It is now broken.

Answer (score 20):

You're browsing to the **Report Server web service**, typically `http://server/ReportServer`. Sounds like you're after the **Report Manager** website, typically `http://server/Reports`.

**Web Service URL:**

[image]

**Report Manager URL:**

[image]

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your report server and type the following in the url link:
`127.0.0.1/reports`

Answer (score 0):

All good answers to work through the issue.

An additional suggestion is the Web Portal URL binding. I bunged it up when a HTTPS binding was added.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).