# SSRS reporting server error

Tags: reporting-services, server

SSRS reporting server did not show me the beautiful interface. It only shows me the directory of folders. Is this the fire wall problem or something else?  What should i do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712569/ssrs-reports-is-showing-as-listed-directory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make you link something like this: http://server:port/Reports. Now it's probably something like http://server:port/Reportserver.